# Typescript: Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type string

Tags: typescript

[image: screenshot of error]

I am getting this error `Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of (a list of strings)`.

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (selectedConnection) {
      wallet.connect(selectedConnection)
    }
  }, [selectedConnection])
```

`selectedConnection` is a string and `wallet.connect` takes a string.

I've changed it to

```
selectedConnection:
    | null
    | 'authereum'
    | 'fortmatic'
    | 'frame'
    | 'injected'
    | 'portis'
    | 'squarelink'
    | 'provided'
    | 'torus'
    | 'walletconnect'
    | 'walletlink'
```

and it works.

Why is this even necessary?

Why does Typescript fail here?

Answer (score 2):

Because `selectedConnection` is a `string` of any arbitrary string value, while `wallet.connect` accepts an arugment that is of a specific union type of strings. That's why. You will need to add a type guard for `selectedConnection`, if you are not sure what its possible values are, prior to invoking `wallet.connect()`.

In layman's terms, `wallet.connect()` only accepts a subset of all `string` values, but you are providing it with **any** `string` value. That is the main reason of the error: type incompatibility.

And for that reason, that is why when you narrow the type of `selectedConnection` to a union type then it works again, because now the type of `selectionConnection` is compatible with the type of the argument accepted by `wallet.connection()`.